# Empty productions in RFC 5234 (Augmented BNF)

Tags: syntax, grammar, rfc

Does Augmented BNF (as specified by [RFC 5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234)) allow matches to empty string?

From reading grammar of the Augmented BNF itself (section 4, ABNF Definition of ABNF) it seems to me that the only way is to use empty quotes (`""`):

```
empty-rule = ""
```

or

```
empty-alternative = some-rule-1 / some-rule-2 / ""
```

while syntax like

```
invalid-empty-rule =
```

is not allowed.

Am I right? Why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rule with an empty right-hand side is clearly not allowed, since we have:

```
rule           =  rulename defined-as elements c-nl
```

and `elements` cannot match an empty sequence. (That's backed up by the actual text, which defines `elements` as "**one or more** rule names or terminal specifications".)

It appears to me that both `""` and `0FOO` (where `FOO` is any non-terminal) are legal `elements`, and the only possible interpretation of either of them would be an empty sequence. On the other hand, I don't believe I've ever seen either of these formulations, since it is extremely easy to indicate that an element is optional, and it is much more normal to write `[NAME]` than to define `NAME` with an alternative including an empty string.

Comment: Somehow I didn't realize that making an element optional would do as well.

Comment: And also I didn't saw `0FOO` as an option. Yet it feels FAR WORSE than `""`.

Comment: It looks to me like rfc3986 has a case of 0FOO, which is what brought me here: path-empty = 0<pchar> . Yes, it's really really weird.